# Prove that spans $\mathcal{V}$ spans $\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=\pmatrix{-1 & 0\\ 2 & 1},B=\pmatrix{2 & -1\\ 1 & 0},C=\pmatrix{1 & 2\\ 0 & -1},D=\pmatrix{0 & 1\\ -1 & 2}$

and $\mathcal{V}=(A,B,C,D)$.

My objective is to show that $\mathcal{V}$ spans $\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and that $\mathcal{V}$ is a basis for $\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

I have shown that:

$A + B −C + 3D=\pmatrix{0 & 0\\ 0 & 8}$,

$D + A − B + 3C=\pmatrix{0 & 8\\ 0 & 0}$,

$C + D − A + 3B=\pmatrix{8 & 0\\ 0 & 0}$,

$B +C − D + 3A=\pmatrix{0 & 0\\ 8 & 0}$.

From that I can see that it's possible to create linear combinations to get the following matrices:

$\pmatrix{0 & 1\\ 0 & 0},\pmatrix{0 & 0\\ 0 & 1},\pmatrix{0 & 0\\ 1 & 0},\pmatrix{1 & 0\\ 0 & 0}\in\text{span}(\mathcal{V})$.

How do I proceed?

Comment: You can also work with coordinates. For example, $A=\pmatrix{-1 & 0\\ 2 & 1} = -1 \pmatrix{1 & 0\\ 0 & 0}+2\pmatrix{0 & 0\\ 1 & 0}+ 1\pmatrix{0 & 0\\ 0& 1} = (-1,0,2,1)_B$. After writing the matrices in this form you can check if they form a basis as you would usually do.

Comment: You have shown that any matrix in $M_{2\times2}(\Bbb R)$ can be written as a linear combination of $A,B,C,D$. These are $4$ vectors that span $M_{2\times2}(\Bbb R)$. What does this tell you about the linear dependence/independence?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri That the elements in $\mathcal{V}$ are linearly independent, right? How do I formally show that $\mathcal{V}$ spans $\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @samsepi0 You have already shown that the standard basis of $M_{2\times2}(\Bbb R)$ can be generated by a linear combination of $A,B,C,D$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not guess. Consider the basis
$$
\mathscr{B}=\left\{
E_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
E_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
E_3=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
E_4=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\right\}
$$
so the coordinate vectors of $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ with respect to $\mathscr{B}$ are the columns of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is easily seen to have rank $4$. Therefore the coordinate vectors of $A,B,C,D$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ which is equivalent to stating that $\{A,B,C,D\}$ is a basis for $\operatorname{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

You can also do in a direct way: show that $\{A,B,C,D\}$ is a linearly independent set. By the theorems on dimension of vector spaces, you can conclude that it is a basis. However, you'll discover that the linear system you have to solve has the same matrix as the $4\times4$ matrix above.

Comment: Regarding linear independence, can I not show that $\mathcal{V}$ is a linearly independent set by observing that $\alpha_1 A+\alpha_2 B+\alpha_3 C+\alpha_4 D$, (where $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4\in\mathbb{R}$) is only equal to 0 when $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3=\alpha_4=0$?

Comment: @samsepi0l Yes, that's the “direct way” I mentioned.

Comment: Which theorem on vector spaces are you referring to?

Comment: @samsepi0l A four element linearly independent set in a space of dimension 4 is a basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as follows, if $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R}),$$
then
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=a\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}+d\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
The L.H.S. is in $\text{Span}(\mathcal{V}),$ hence so is the $R.H.S.,$ so $\mathcal{V}$ is a spanning set. Any set of $4$ vectors spanning a $4$ dimensional vector space is automatically a basis, so $\mathcal{V}$ is a basis for $\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R})$.